# Why I cannot change views page title using views_post_render?

Tags: 7, views

I have view that uses url args: parent term id and term id/ids, so the url structure is like page/%/%

Title pattern for this view is: %1(%2)

However I have few pages with multi tids as second argument, so generated title is strange (very long). I am trying to change this title programmatically:

```
function bip_title_alter_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache)  {

    if ($view->name == 'kategorie_artykulow' && $view->current_display == 'page_9')
    {
        $args = explode(' ', $view->args[1]);
        if (sizeof($args) < 2) {
            return;
        }
        $title_pattern = 'Archiwum Oświadczeń Majątkowych w %dr.';
        $term = taxonomy_term_load($args[0]);
        if (! $term) {
            return;
        }
        $title = sprintf($title_pattern, $term->name);
        drupal_set_title($title);
    }
}

function bip_title_alter_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
    if ($hook == 'views_post_render') {
        $group = $implementations['bip_title_alter'];
        unset($implementations['bip_title_alter']);
        $implementations['bip_title_alter'] = $group;
    }
}
```

but title remains the same, I am sure that I am altering proper view.

Adding another display to view is not good option for me, because I have a lot existing urls and if I create another display with the same url structure and different args config always first display is handling request.

**edit**

I changed my custom module weight in system table to 9999 and I still see that title is altered after my module hook :/ It's so annoying

Comment: Probably the only way is to alter title in template.php in this case

Comment: If you're doing a `drupal_set_title()` early enough, then presumably something's overriding the title you've set. You could try printing out a backtrace from within `drupal_set_title()` and also print out the title passed in. This might show what's causing problems.

Comment: @Andy I am doing this and I see that title is replace after my hook calling

Comment: You can use the backtrace to identify _what_ is replacing the title - and then hopefully either prevent it, change it, or find a way to set the title even later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andy advice the solution is so simple.

Views set title after calling to views_pre_render and views_post_render: (views_plugin_display_page.inc)

```
  // And now render the view.
    $render = $this->view->render();

    // First execute the view so it's possible to get tokens for the title.
    // And the title, which is much easier.
    drupal_set_title(filter_xss_admin($this->view->get_title()), PASS_THROUGH);
```

If there is a get method there is a big chance that setter exists ;)

So calling:

```
$view->set_title($title);
```

inside hook (pre or post) do the job

Answer (score 1):

I always use a [`hook_views_pre_view()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21docs%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7):

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == "foo" && $view->current_display == "bar") {
    $view->display[$view->current_display]->display_options["title"] =
    $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->options["title"] = "The New Title";
  }
}
```

This should then funnel up to be pulled in as the page title, but I never use views directly as pages.

Comment: Thanks still not work, I see that title is altering by different hook that is called alter views_post_render. I should find other way to alter title

Answer (score 0):

I would use [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and alter the views display title.

Refer to http://drupal.org/node/438370 as well.